# pip install behaving unexpectedly macOS

Tags: python, path, pip, aws-cli

I tried to install awscli on my Mac using pip but `aws --version` kept saying `command not found`.

I followed the [Official AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-macos.html#awscli-install-osx-path) exactly, but the problem happened here.

> pip installs programs in the same folder that contains the Python
>   application. Add this folder to your PATH variable.

**This was not true for my case and I have no idea why.**

Following other steps in the doc, I found these information

```
`aws`
Located at: /Users/user1/Library/Python/3.7/bin/aws

`awscli`
Located at: /Users/user1/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-package

`python3`
Located at: /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4/bin
```

From this, we can see that my location for Python3 is **different** from where `aws` or `awscli` is actually installed.
I eventually solved the problem for now by adding `/Users/user1/Library/Python/3.7/bin/aws` to $PATH,
**But what in the world is going on here?**
Please help!

How I located above programs:

For `aws`, I ran `pip3 uninstall awscli` and it showed where it is while prompting to ask if I want to really uninstall awscli.

For `awscli` I ran `pip3 show awscli`

For python3, I followed the process in the [above doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-macos.html#awscli-install-osx-path), which are 
`which python3`, get the path, `ls -al the_path_I_got_from_which_python3`

Comment: did you installed `python3` with `brew` ?

Comment: @LinPy yes I did!

Comment: Nothing is wrong, `pip install --user` installs packages for your user and not for everyone, the installation target in that case is in your home dir under `~/Library/Python/$version`, the executables are placed under `~/Library/Python/$version/bin`. You have to add this directory to `PATH`. This is also mentioned in the docs you linked above.

Comment: then install aws-cli also with brew `https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/awscli`